# In the nuxt project, other files are introduced separately into the store

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js

sorry about my english, How can i in other js files use vuex.store in nuxt project

in store

```
export const state = () => ({
  token: 'test',
  name: '',
  avatar: ''
}),
export const mutations = {
  SET_TOKEN: (state, token) => {
    state.token = token
  }
},
export const getters = {
  token: state => {
    return state.token
  }
}
```

in test.js

```
export function() => {
    //how can i updata vuex token?
}
export function() => {
    //how can i getter vuex token?
}
```

```
export default ({ app, store, route, redirect }) => {
    some code
}
```

it can't work

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Not sure about tests, but in components you should be able to access the Vuex store with `this.$store`.

Comment: But in the nuxt project, you can't use this.$store. in any js.

Answer (score 1):

A basic implementation would look like this

```
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
    computed: {
       // you only need State OR Getter here not both!!! You don't need a 
       // getter for just returning a simple state
       ...mapState('yourStoreName', ['token'])
       ...mapGetters('yourStoreName', ['token']),
    },
    methods: {
       methodThatNeedsToChangeState (){
          this.setToken('newToken')
       },
       ...mapActions('yourStoreName', ['setToken']),
    }
}
```

In your store you need actions though, you don't call mutations directly! Because Mutations can't be asynchronous.

```
export const actions = {
   setToken: (context, token) => {
      context.commit(SET_TOKEN, token)
   }
},
```

I would highly recommend you to study the Vuex documentation in more detail.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: ![picture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23123540/60789196-1075db80-a191-11e9-80f2-919dedf2aa18.png)I don't know how to display the picture.  Can you help me see the picture and help me solve the problem? Thank you.